# Tikz picture inside a box

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, examples

I need to use a tikz picture and some text with equations, inside a frame or something like this, to add an highlighted example in my page.
I tried using tcolorbox but it doesn't allow to use tikzpicture inside.
Here is the code I want to highlight:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

This is the an example text:
\begin{equation}
1=2
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) (a) {a};
\node at (1,0) (b) {b};
\draw (a)--(b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I need the image below the text, minipages are not a solution.
Any answer helps, thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit off-topic, but `\centering{}` does not really make sense as `\centering` is a switch and does not take any argument. Also, there's a typo: `\enf{figure}`. Compilable code would make helping you easier. o( +_+ )o

Comment: You want all of this inside the same box? If so, you can't have part of your content within a `figure` environment (which is a float) and part without.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Somethink like this: [Example: Boxes with text and math](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/boxes-with-text-and-math/) ?

Comment: @AliceM. \centering is centering the picture in my page. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @FedericoCaccia Of course, but there is no need for those braces. They are confusing since they do not reflect the way the command is meant to be used, and they serve no real purpose.

Comment: @AliceM. Now I understand, perfect!

Comment: @Michael Palmer Yes I want to have all of this inside the same box. Do you have any idea to do it?

Comment: Hi @Bobyandbob! I tried to minimalize the code as much as I could!

Comment: @FedericoCaccia The problem was not really the minimization of the code, but rather the fact that it is not a complete document: there is no `\documentclass` and stuff. By the way, sorry if I sound rude in all those comments.

Comment: @AliceM. thanks for your recommendations, now I changed the input in order to make an MWE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can include `tikzpicture` in `tcolorbox`, at least if you use `listings`. I know that you said not to use `minipage`, but not why noy to use it. To me this is the natural start of such a problem, so I included a solution for that as well. And I expanded the MWE with some `lipsum` text and boxes around nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}
\newtcblisting{EvalBox}[2][]{%
  colback=white,
  arc=0pt,
  boxrule=0.5pt,
  text only,
  title=#2,#1}
%% 
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
%% First
\begin{EvalBox}{}
  \lipsum[2]
  \begin{equation}
    1=2
  \end{equation}

  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] at (0,0) (a) {a};
    \node[circle,draw] at (1,0) (b) {b};
    \draw[->] (a)--(b);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{EvalBox}

%% Second version, using minipage
\noindent
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{1.0\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
  \lipsum[2]
  \begin{equation}
    1=2
  \end{equation}

  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] at (0,0) (a) {a};
    \node[circle,draw] at (1,0) (b) {b};
    \draw[->] (a)--(b);
  \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

A version with `tcolorbox` not using `listing` can also be done:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white]
  \lipsum[2]
  \begin{equation}
    1=2
  \end{equation}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] at (0,0) (a) {a};
    \node[circle,draw] at (1,0) (b) {b};
    \draw[->] (a)--(b);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just for sake of completeness: `tikzpicture` can be used inside a `tcolorbox` without restrictions - there is no need for the `listings` way (but, of course, this works).

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm, You are right, I have added a version without `listings`.

Answer (score 7):

I might have misunderstood the question, but here is a try:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0,0) (a) {a};
        \node at (1,0) (b) {b};
        \draw (a)--(b);

        \node[above = \baselineskip of current bounding box] {%
            \begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}
                Text or whatever you want to put here.

                \begin{equation*}
                    1 = 2
                \end{equation*}
            \end{minipage}%
        };
        \draw (current bounding box.north west) rectangle (current bounding box.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Quick explanations: once the main elements of the picture are drawn, I create a node that gets positioned right on top of everything (above the “current bounding box”, by a distance relative to `\baselineskip` because it's slightly less dirty). Finally, I draw a rectangle around the final bounding box. … It's a bit overkill, now that I think about it.

By the way, I'm pretty sure tikzpictures *can* be put in tcolorboxes, since I used tcolorboxes to show examples in the documentation of a pseudo-package I wrote, and these were full of tikz stuff: http://www.alicem.net/files/oths/pointbox.zip

Comment: amazing, it helps me! I really appreciate your time!

Answer (score 5):

Here is something that doesn't use minipages (for this particular problem).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [text width = 0.9\linewidth] (first) {
            Text or whatever you want to put here. 
        };
        \node [below=\baselineskip] at (first) (eq) {$1=2$};
        \node [below left=\baselineskip] at (eq) (a) {a};
        \node at ([xshift=1cm] a) (b) {b};
        \draw (a)--(b);
        \node [draw, rectangle, fit=(first)(eq)(a)(b)]{};   
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: text in a box]

Comment: Welcome! Croeso!